# Use case for Optional Catch Binding

Tags: javascript, try-catch

So I'm walking through all the new features released in the past ES. I don't understand why do we need this Optional Catch Binding.

```
try{
abc()
} catch {
console.log('issue occurred'); //but what's the issue?
}
```

Don't we want to know the reason of failed to execute `abc()`? Whenand what is the suitable use case to apply this Optional Catch Binding?

Comment: This is suitable for situations where we know the type of error that the block in ```try``` might throw and the reason behind it. e.g. parsing a non JSON string in the ```try``` block would raise a ```JSON Exception``` indicating the string is not a valid JSON

Comment: @KunalKukreja Make sense, but why would one throw own exception within try block instead having `catch` to handle? I think there're also chances whereby we missed throwing error.